# SPListItem returns a different Item.UniqueID for each version

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I need a value that is unique even when versioning is turned on in the library.  Is there a different property I should be calling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spListItem class has a versions object that contains all the versions of the object. Each [SPListItemVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437481.aspx) has a VersionID property.

The Item.UniqueID does uniquely identify each list item. Each version of that listitem is not considered by SharePoint to be separate from the item. So chances are that UniqueID is fine.

Comment: Thanks Nat.  This is what I was hoping was true.  I didn't have access to my dev machine and as always the StackOverflow community had a prompt answer!

Comment: No worries. I'll admit to doing a double take on why you were asking :)